# Azure File Service "PUT Range" REST API 'InvalidHeaderValue' error

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to upload a file to Azure File Service using the REST API. After creating the file, the 'put range' request fails with 'InvalidHeaderValue'

So far I've successfully created the file using the documentation found here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file

After that, I try to put content into the newly created file following the documentation found here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-range

here is an example of the URI I'm using. It look correct next to the example in the doc.

```py
uri = 'https://<account>.file.core.windows.net/<share>/<directory>/<file>?comp=range&<sas token>'
```

I get the content of the file with...

```py
with open(file.txt, mode='rb') as fh:
    data = fh.read()
```

My headers look like this...

```py
headers = {
    'x-ms-write':'update',
    'x-ms-date':'Wed, 10  Apr 2019 22:14:17 GMT',
    'x-ms-version':'2018-03-28',
    'x-ms-range':'bytes=0-' + str(len(data)),
    'Content-Length':str(len(data) + 1)
}
```

Request...

```py
requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

The response code I get back is a 400 and the return header is this...

```
{
'Content-Length': '322', 
'Content-Type': 'application/xml', 
'Server': 'Windows-Azure-File/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0', 
'x-ms-request-id': '23642a26-e01a-0049-35da-ef0109000000', 
'x-ms-version': '2018-03-28', 
'x-ms-error-code': 'InvalidHeaderValue', 
'Date': 'Wed, 10 Apr 2019 20:14:46 GMT'
}
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: How big is the data you’re trying to upload?

Comment: @GauravMantri The data is very small.  about 46KB.  Its just some test data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to the incorrect value of `x-ms-range` and `Content-Length` .

The correct one should like below:

```
headers={
    #other headers
    'x-ms-range':'bytes=0-' + str(len(data)-1),
    'Content-Length':str(len(data))    
}
```

My sample code as below, and works fine:

```
import requests

uri = r'https://xxx.file.core.windows.net/test/good222.txt?comp=range&sv=2018-03-28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-04-12T10:59:42Z&st=2019-04-12T02:59:42Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxxxx'

with open("D:\\hello.txt",mode='rb') as fh:
    data = fh.read()

print(len(data))
headers={
    'x-ms-write':'update',
    'x-ms-date':'Fri, 12 Apr 2019 06:40:14 GMT',
    'x-ms-version':'2018-03-28',
    'x-ms-range':'bytes=0-' + str(len(data)-1),
    'Content-Length':str(len(data))    
}

r= requests.put(uri,data=data,headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers)
```

The result(the file also updated on the azure portal):

[image]

Please also note that the file(locally) length should not be longer than the one you want to update on azure file share.